# Failure on build with Gradle on command line with an android studio project : Xlint error

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle

When I try to build an android project with gradle with this command :

```
> gradlew clean build assembleRelease
```

It gives me this error :

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.  
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.  
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

I can build this project and make the APK in Studio.

Is there a way to configure Gradle to make a compilation ignoring Xlint notifications ?

OR, can I use other parameters, to make the release from command-line with gradle/gradlew ?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

It's a nice warning, not an error. To see the complete lint report you can add these lines to build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
}
```

If you really want to get rid of those warnings:

1. Don't use deprecated API
2. Use @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

Comment: The IDE is unable to recognize 'options' in my case :(

Answer (score 43):

This is fairly obvious from @shakalaca's answer, but if you have code old enough to get the deprecation warning, you may also have code old enough to use unchecked operations, e.g. a `List` without the parameterized type as in `List<String>`. This will get you an additional warning:

```
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

You can just expand the compiler args block to include that as well:

```
allprojects {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation" << "-Xlint:unchecked"
    }
}
```

Comment: How to do this in Visual Studio?