# Java - Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API

Tags: java, compiler-errors, runtime-error, command-prompt, jcreator

I'm trying to compile and run my project from the command prompt. I'm using JCreator for my project. I can't find any solution.

this is the error i got in the command prompt :

```
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

And oh, I've also tried to run the project in the JCreator as well. But, it doesn't display my GUI Program. I had already set a certain Java file/class as main file/class.

I'm not sure if it's because i didn't set as main properly or is something else.
Hope anyone can help me or suggest solutions. Thanks! :)

Comment: It simply means that you are calling methods which have been marked with a `@Deprecated` annotation. If you compile with `-Xlint:deprecation` as a command line argument, it will tell you which ones those are.

Comment: Ahh i see, Thanks! now i know which ones (:

Comment: You can have more information in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18743837/4795898).